# APK files download will not work

Tags: installation, apk, ios

In Facebook Messenger, I found this slot machine I wanted to download. I use iPhone 8 Plus for everything along with my Windows 10 computer at home/work computer, plus I'm always on Google as my main email provider. I just switched to iPhone only for tracking my kiddo so I'm still not sure how all this will work. I get the link to download it on my phone. I open it up from my computer, thinking it would be best for more viewing on my monitor. It says:

- android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.VIBRATE
- android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.VIBRATE

"Waiting for device...."

From iPhone, I have to open it in Safari. Well, I made Google my browser and do everything with that on an Apple phone. Stupid really, I should go back to Android, just can't afford it right now.

So that is why I'm trying to download this link and it did. It just can't open it after saving it without some type of installer. So APK files are where I'm having issues.

I'm a newbie here.  I really need to be educated with simple step-by-step help. Can anyone please try to help me?

Comment: `.apk` files are meant to run in Android OS only, just as `.exe` files are meant for Windows. You can't run files meant for one type of OS for another. It may be possible to run this on windows on [emulator](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-emulator) or [sideload ing](https://www.androidpolice.com/windows-11-apk-install-guide/), which has it's own limitations //I am not familiar with either but do know that there is a learning curve// On Chromebook you can run Android apps without any fuss// **tl:dr** not possible the way you are trying

Comment: First of all, APK (Android apps) can't run on iOS. That's given. Second, when you opened it on the computer, did another app/emulator appear? Otherwise, what Windows version are you using? AFAIK, APK also can't be opened on Windows by default, so there's something else that intercepts the installation.